# Fetch the list of command line parameters in txt file ----> " setup.exe /? " or " setup.exe /help "

Tags: installation, windows-installer, exe, sccm

I am trying to automate installation of applications. Specific exe files have slight differences in their input parameter. So, I am trying to parse the list programmatically.
For that, I would need to result of   `Setup.exe /?` or `Setup.exe /help`
in a txt, csv etc.,

Currently, the result will come as a pop-up toast, which cannot be inputted to a program.

Comment: A couple of quick links for now: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53296461/129130), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul - I am trying to find out a way to export the values generated by setup.exe /? as a txt etc., Unfortunately these links explain more about the command line parameters itself and not the way to fetch them programmatically

Comment: I have never tried this - do you do a pipe (Sample: `dir >> list.txt`) from command line and it never gets into a text file? Every setup.exe can be different. There is no set way to find these things that I know of. There was a tool which seemed to search for command switches with string searches of the binary itself, but it triggered a lot of malware alerts so I stopped linking to it. I will have a look to see if I can find what it is called. I would check [SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) first.

Comment: [Process Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10924825/129130) can be used to show embedded strings in running binaries.